# Transform function to useCallback

Tags: reactjs, usecallback

I want to rewrite a function like:

```
function useQuery() {
  return new URLSearchParams(useLocation().search);
}
```

to preferred by React `useCallback` form, my best guess was:

```
const useQuery = useCallback(
  () => {
    return new URLSearchParams(useLocation().search);
  },
  [useLocation]
);
```

The error which I got:

> React Hook "useLocation" cannot be called inside a callback. React
> Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React
> Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Does it mean that I cannot transform my function to `useCallback`?

Comment: funny how I tried the exact same thing ! here, have my upvote

Comment: Thanks! Have a good day without bugs!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`useLocation` is a hook and should be called directly in the component.  Its *result* however can be used in a callback.  For example:

```
const location = useLocation();
const useQuery = useCallback(
    () => {
        return new URLSearchParams(location.search);
    },
    [location]
);
```

Though since `location` is an object and you really only care about the `search` value, the comparison to determine what's changed for the `useCallback` hook is likely more accurate with just the simple value:

```
const { search } = useLocation();
const useQuery = useCallback(
    () => {
        return new URLSearchParams(search);
    },
    [search]
);
```